# Generating function for sum to min

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I'm trying to find the ogf of the number $f(n, m)$ of weakly increasing mappings from $[n]\to [m]$ such that $i \mapsto j \implies j \leq i$ for each $i\in [n]$. Let $k$ be the image of $n$. Then the remaining $n - 1$ elements of $[n]$ must be mapped to numbers $\leq k$ and there are $f(n - 1, k)$ such mappings. Summing over $k$, we get
$$f(n, m) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\min(n, m)}f(n - 1, k)$$
If $F_n(x)$ is the ogf for $f(n, m)$, is there any way to express the ogf for the RHS of this recurrence in terms of $F_{n - 1}(x)$? Presumably some variation of
$$\frac{F_{n-1}(x)}{1-x}$$
?

Comment: The condition that i mapsto j implies i <= j is distinct from the condition of it being weakly increasing. it must satisfy both conditions. this explains why the sum stops at min(n, m) instead of m. if we only required it to be weakly increasing, then the gf would be x/(1-x)^{n+1}

Comment: Your recurrence relation is correct, but it does not lead to a generating function proof. $$\begin{align}
F_n(x)
  &=\sum_{m\ge 1}F(n,m)x^m
\\&=\sum_{m\ge 1}\sum_{k=1}^{\min(m,n)}F(n-1,k)x^m
\\&=\sum_{k=1}^nF(n-1,k)\sum_{m\ge k}x^m
\\&=\sum_{k=1}^nF(n-1,k)\frac{x^k}{1-x}
\\&=\frac1{1-x}\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{n}}F(n-1,k)x^k
\end{align}$$ If the upper limit were $\infty$ instead of $\color{red}n$, the inner summation would be $F_{n-1}(x)$. But we are stuck, since there is no way to algebraically relate $\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{n}}F(n-1,k)x^k$ to $F_{n-1}(x)$.

Comment: It is possible to give a generating function proof, but you need to start with a harder-to-find recurrence relation for $f(n,m)$. The functions you are counting are in bijection with lattice paths from $(1,1)$ to $(n,m)$ which stay below the line $y=x$ (at least when $m\le n$). If you break up a path at the last point it touches $y=x$, you get a Catalan-like recurrence of these paths in terms of smaller paths, which translates to a generating function equation. But it is simpler to just count the paths directly using the reflection principle.